# Get color Image not in the frame ready event

Tags: c#, kinect, openkinect, nui

I have some problem with the kinect.
when I try to get color Image from the event: Sensor_AllFramesReady everything is ok.
example:

```
using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame()) {
    //save image for print
    if (colorFrame == null) {
        return;
    }
    byte[] colorData = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
    colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(colorData);
    int averagedImage = colorFrame.Width * PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel / 8;
    int stride = colorFrame.Width * 4;
    pictureBitmap = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, stride);
}
```

But when I try to do the same code outside the event with

```
using (ColorImageFrame Image = Sensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(10)) {

}
```

I get error : 
"This API cannot be called when an event listener has been set"

I try to remove the event before calling this function but this don't change anything

Comment: Do you delete this line?  `kinectSensor.AllFramesReady += new EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(kinectSensor_AllFramesReady);`

Comment: no, before calling the above function I call to:  Sensor.AllFramesReady -= Sensor_AllFramesReady;

Comment: but I want to use that event for other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choice, event handler or poll method. You can use the event and save the last frame to use it some else place.

Comment: That was exactly what I did. but this is waste of memory and run time

Comment: Save the last ColorImageFrame in a global variable is a waste of memory? It's just an image and don't need any process. Please explain in more details why this is not a solution.

Comment: I did not explain myself correctly, the event works 30 times per second, if every time I do the above calculation, then it takes time. The problem here is time and not memory.  There is no solution to do both?

Comment: Kinect Sdk don't allow use both. Then why you want to use both? What exactly you want to archive?

Comment: I do a regular paint application - for this I need the event. I want to add function to print screen( the canvas that the user draw on him), in this function I want to add to the canvas a picture of the user from the kinect sensor. are you sure that kinect don't allow both? why?

Comment: Kinect SDK don't allow that. And there's no need to use both methods. Check this link, maybe is what you are trying to do: [Kinect Paint](http://paint.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I am already use this code, this not help to me. do you have link for this issue - that kinect don't allow both. I you will add print method to this code that include image from the kinect?

Comment: I maintain that my answer is correct. There's no need to use both methods (it's not posible). Just don't do any processing on the event method. Check source code of the samples in the [Kinect Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx)