# KinectSDK poll after using events

Tags: c#, xna, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have two sections of a Kinect app I'm making. There's a WPF menu which eventually directs the user to an XNA Game.

The problem is the WPF controls I'm using (like KinectRegion) are adding event listeners to things like AllFramesReady on the KinectSensor object. And as soon as I try to poll for skeleton data in my XNA game, I get the following error:

```
This API cannot be called when an event listener has been set
```

**My question**: How can I reset everything in the KinectSDK so I have a clean slate when starting my XNA game? Or at the very least, get it into a state where I can poll for skeleton data successfully.

I don't know what methods the WPF controls are attaching to handle the events, so I can't explicitly remove them from the event.

Similar issue: [Get color Image not in the frame ready event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210931/get-color-image-not-in-the-frame-ready-event)

Comment: Well, I ended up just switching my XNA game over to an event model rather than polling, which works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to use event handler and polling method at one time. Kinect API won't support that. better way is to use global variable for your polling method and use it on anywhere that you want.